# Solving applications of power series.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, power-series

The region bounded by the curves $$ y = \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x} $$
$$ y = 0, x = \frac{1}{2}$$

is rotated around the y-axis.

Find the volume of the solid of revolution with accuracy to within $10^{-2}.$

How to solve this problem? I've never seen any kind of this question. T T

Comment: A guess:  those are three curves which bound the area which is being rotated around the $y$ axis, namely $y=\sin(x^2)/x$, $y=0$ (a straight line), and $x={1\over2}$ (also a straight line).  I would also guess that they only want $x\ge 0$, but maybe they want the area being rotated to go all the way to $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: If you use "cylindrical shells", you'll at least be rid of that annoying denominator.  It does look like you need power series for the integrand, which will just mean replacing $ \ x \ $ in the Macluarin series with $ \ x^2 \ $ .  Also, the fact that the poser only wants two decimal places of precision indicates that you won't need many terms:  the series approximation will be a nice, short polynomial. (If you graph the function, the section you're working with is _almost_ a straight line!)